# SQL: Check if n consecutive records are greater than some value

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that contains numbers. I have to find whether there is any case where in n consecutive numbers are greater than some threshold value m.
For e.g.

```
id      delta         
---------------
1        10  
4        15 
11       22 
23       23  
46       21
57       9
```

So here, if I want to know if there are 3 consecutive records where value is more than 20 then I should get True. And False when I check for 4 consecutive records. Is that possible? This is on Apache Spark SQL. Thanks.

Comment: Yes possible. Which `DBMS`?..

Comment: As mentioned, it's on Apache Spark. thanks.

Comment: Initially it is not tagged.. I don't know apache-spark.. Try the below answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using lag:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(val, 1) over (order by id) as val_1,
             lag(val, 2) over (order by id) as val_2
      from t
     ) t
where val > 20 and val_1 > 20 and val_2 > 20;
```

This returns the first row that is part of each three-some.  If you just want true/false:

```
select (case when count(*) > 0 then 'true' else 'false' end)
from (select t.*,
             lag(val, 1) over (order by id) as val_1,
             lag(val, 2) over (order by id) as val_2
      from t
     ) t
where val > 20 and val_1 > 20 and val_2 > 20;
```

EDIT:

I missed the part about not wanting more than 3.  So, you can enhance this:

```
select (case when count(*) > 0 then 'true' else 'false' end)
from (select t.*,
             lag(val, 1) over (order by id) as val_1,
             lag(val, 2) over (order by id) as val_2,
             lag(val, 3) over (order by id) as val_3,
             lead(val, 1) over (order by id) as val_next_1
      from t
     ) t
where (val_3 <= 20 or val_3 is null) and
      (val_2 > 20 and val_1 > 20 and val > 20) and
      (val_next_1 <= 20 or val_next_1 is null);
```

It is a little tricky because the values can be at the beginning or end of the rows.

Comment: this won't return `false` if there are four consecutive values greater than the threshold

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I will try this.

Comment: The interesting part however would be to have those `3` and `4` threshold values declaratively set, otherwise I would also go for using `LAG` and `LEAD`

Comment: Is it possible to configure this for any number of consecutive records instead of 3?

Comment: @Nagesh . . . Yes but you should probably ask a new question.  Be very clear on the database you are using and how long the sequences should be.

Comment: I have posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55739086/how-to-check-if-n-consecutive-events-from-kafka-stream-is-greater-or-less-than-t